# Which criteria should I use to evaluate a time series for stationarity?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, acf-pacf

I have been given two criteria to evaluate the stationarity of a time series:

1. A stationary series will have no sample acf (SAC) or sample pacf (SPAC) values outside of confidence bounds on the chart.
2. In general, it can be shown that for nonseasonal data

If the SAC of a time series either cuts off fairly quickly or dies down fairly quickly, then the time series values should be considered stationary.

If the SAC of a time series values dies down extremely slowly, then the time series values should be considered nonstationary.

- SAC = sample acf,  SPAC = sample pacf

There are four variations of time series: seasonal, trend, cyclical and random variations.

An example of a linear trend model with no seasonal variation is y_t = a+bt+e_t.

In determining stationarity of non seasonal data which criterion should I use? Is the fact that nonseasonal time series is mentioned important here? It would seem that the confidence bounds on the chart would always be important.

Comment: You second point is incomplete, it ends with a comma...

Comment: Hi @Mary Marlon. Would you be able to provide an expression for your time series process, whether AR, MA, or ARMA?

Comment: Please see updated post. Any non seasonal time series is mentioned.  I am aware of the guidelines for choosing seasonal and nonseasonal operators. None of the guideline tables I have seen even mention confidence bounds.